# Convert a hyperlink into a button

Tags: php, javascript, html

In a php page, there is a javascript function at the beginning like this:-

```
< script type="text/javascript">
    function updatecart(sid,fid,i)
    {
        var qty = document.getElementById(i+"qty").value;
        location.href="index826.php?section=cc&page=cart_update&sid="+sid+"&fid="+fid+"&i="+i+"&qty="+qty;
    }
< /script>
```

and at bottom, there is a hyperlink that links to the same page, and call the function, like this:-

```
< input type="text" id="'.$i.'qty" value="'.$qty['qty'].'" size = "4"/>
< a href="#" onclick="updatecart('.$shopid.','.$fid.','.$i.');">Refresh< /a>
```

Actually, I would like to convert the hyperlink into a normal button like this:-

```
< input name="button2" type="submit" value="Refresh"/>
```

Is it possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure is.  Just set the button's `onclick` and use `type='button'` rather than `submit`.

```
<input name="button2" type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="updatecart('.$shopid.','.$fid.','.$i.');" />
```

PHP will fill in the values of `$shopid, $fid, $i`, same as it did with the hyperlink.

Comment: I can change the outlook of the link to a button, however, the function is no longer working anymore :(

Comment: @Ham As long as you place the button in the same location the `<a>` was in (after function definition) it should work exactly the same way.

Comment: You must maintain proper quoting in the PHP code that surrounds it.

Comment: < td>< input type="text" id="'.$i.'qty" value="'.$qty['qty'].'" size = "4"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Refresh" onclick="updatecart('.$shopid.','.$fid.','.$i.');">< /td> is it acceptable?? Thank you...

Comment: @Ham, no change `type='submit'` to `type='button'` per my example.

Comment: @Ham If you're satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.  Do the same for answers of your previous questions, and you'll receive more and swifter help on Stack Overflow in the future.